# How to automatically show a dialog that ask confirmation when the user click in an image using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xhtml

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and I have this doubt.

I have this clickable image:

```
 <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/delete.png" alt="remove"
      id="RemoveProject"
      style="cursor: pointer;"
      title="remove"
      onClick="submitMyProjectAction('<s:property value="idProjectInfo"/>', this.id)"
  />
```

As you can see when the user click on the image it is performed this JavaScript function that simply submit a form:

```
function submitMyProjectAction(id, imgId) {
    alert(imgId);

    document.getElementById("projectActionId").value = id;
    document.getElementById("clickedActionId").value = imgId;
    document.getElementById('myProjectAction').submit();
}
```

I know that should exist a way to automatically open something like a dialog that ask confirmation for this operation. So if the user click on yes the submitMyProjectAction() JavaScript function is performed.

But I can't remember the name of this stuff. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`confirm()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.confirm) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use jQuery UI, with a modal confirmation (http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

So, when user clicks the image, that modal form will show. It will have two buttons, and clicking "Confirm Action" will trigger the function you want to, `submitMyProjectAction()`;

It will log something like this:

```
function BeforeSubmitMyProjectOption() {
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
          resizable: false,
          height:140,
          modal: true,
          buttons: {
            "Confirm Action": function() {
              submitMyProjectAction(id, imgId)
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel Action: function() {
              $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
          }
        });
```